# Cannot DROP CONSTRAINT in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, umbraco

I am trying to remove a constraint as I am getting the following message whilst trying to upgrade a website:

[image]

I have located the offending constraint in the database:

[image]

I have tried dropping the constraint using the following query in SSMS:

```
USE [Docs10]
GO

/****** Object:  Index [IX_umbracoPropertyData_VersionId]    Script Date: 21/03/2024 11:02:13 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[umbracoPropertyData] DROP CONSTRAINT [IX_umbracoPropertyData_VersionId]
GO
```

But when running the script - nothing happens and the error still persists.

What is the proper way to drop the constraint?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Are you sure `IX_umbracoPropertyData_VersionId` is a Foreign key Constraint? I would *hope* you prefix your foreign key names with `FK` (if using prefixes); `IX` is normally for indexes, which a Foreign Key Constraint is *not*. As you show you have indexes with the `IX` prefix in the image it must be very confusing to have constraints with the prefix as well.

Comment: First you need to drop this contrain where it's used as unique key Or truncate table where it is used if you restoring data than it will reinsert the data

Comment: I have no idea because I didn't create the database - I restored it from a backup. I just ended up right clicking on it and deleting it - I didn't do that before because I was unsure whether that would break the entire thing.

Comment: @ThomA I don't see foreign keys mentioned anywhere in the question. This is an index backing a **unique** constraint

Comment: *"It is being used an a unqiue key constraint"* @MartinSmith . You probably couldn't find it, as the OP is yet to fix their images.

Comment: @ThomA -unique constraint <> foreign key https://dbfiddle.uk/gXYUPcWT

Comment: Then i have misread it. If only the OP would paste text as text, @MartinSmith ... I've reopened, feel free to find a different appropriate duplicate; they will be plenty (I've burned my close vote).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open Indexes

Step 2: Find the constraint that is causing the problem - in this case IX_umbracoPropertyData_VersionId

Step 3: Delete it.